# pubspec.yaml = the asset directory not exist what is wrong?

Tags: flutter

pubspec.yaml = the asset directory not exist what is wrong?

[image: PICTURE PROVIDED IN THE LINK]

Comment: share plain code or screenshots rather than images.

Answer (score 3):

The asset folder should be at the same level as your pubspec.yaml.

If the warning is still shown after moving the folder, please check if this is [an incorrect warning](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1090) by using one of your assets in the app and verifying that it is actually not being found.

Comment: In order to know if that is my problem my question is ..where 'EXACTLY' to put it? I should mention im running it on chrome

Comment: As mentioned in my first sentence: the asset folder should be located in exactly the same directory as your pubspec.yaml

Comment: tnx .. so that would be the web folder so in that case i guess it is the incorrect warning the is still loading its. just not going to show the images :(

Comment: @My-wspace No that would not be the web folder. That *should* be the folder **above** the web folder. As kevlatus says, it should be the **same level** as your `pubspec.yaml`. Whether you're compiling for web, mobile, or desktop is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

put asset folder in root directory of flutter project and you'll be fine.

Comment: It did not work in the flutter project ..can you define project directory?

Comment: 2 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dev_dependencies:
source_span   *1.8.0   *1.8.0      *1.8.0      1.8.1   
test_api      *0.2.19  *0.2.19     *0.2.19     0.3.0   
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.